# Bluetooth Socket is blocked on Read

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin, bluetooth

I´m working in a project about an app for Android and iOS (with Xamarin Forms).

This app will be able to discover and connect with a OBD2 and communicate with it for get some data about a car.

My problem is the next; in Android, when I start to send and receive data from the device, the first communication is ok, I sent a ASCII code and device responds to me. But next, I sent another ASCII code and when I want to Read, the method BluetoothSocket.InputStream.IsDataAvailable() is false, so I can´t read more, and I don´t know how can do for "unblock" this read for read next reponse.

My code:

To get the Bluetooth Socket.-

```
 socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.Uuid);
```

//if first fails
     socket = device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.Uuid);

To send information to the Device (first calls):

```
 byte[] cmd = new byte[6];
        cmd[0] = 02;
        cmd[1] = 65;
        cmd[2] = 84;
        cmd[3] = 32;
        cmd[4] = 90;
        cmd[5] = 03;
        //cmd[6] = 04;

        socket.OutputStream.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
        if (Read().Equals("")){
            throw new System.Exception();
        }
        socket.OutputStream.Flush();

        cmd[0] = 02;
        cmd[1] = 65;
        cmd[2] = 84;
        cmd[3] = 32;
        cmd[4] = 68;
        cmd[5] = 03;
        //cmd = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AT Z");
        socket.OutputStream.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("After second write InputStream.IsDataAvailable="+socket.InputStream.IsDataAvailable()); //Always false
        if (Read().Equals("")){
            throw new System.Exception();
        }
        socket.OutputStream.Flush();
```

To Read the response:

```
  private  string Read()
    {
        //También probado con BufferedReader.ready() para comprobar si el stream está listo para leer; mismo resultado.



        string data = ""; 
        try

        {               
            System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            char c;
            byte a;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            //Este tipo de socket no soporta Timeouts
            if (socket.InputStream.IsDataAvailable()) //only entry first time
            {                                       
                int bytes = socket.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                //while (((a = (byte)socket.InputStream.ReadByte()) > -1))
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
                {
                    a = buffer[i];

                    c = (char)a;
                    if (c.Equals('\r')) //Comprobado \r es el último caracter, no llega a  ETX
                    {

                        break;

                    }
                    builder.Append(c);
                }
                data = builder.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Información: " + data);

                socket.InputStream.Flush();



            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input Stream no disponible");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error de lectura :"+e.Message);

        }

        return data;

    }
```

I would like to resolv this, because I have to sent a lot of information to the device without waiting.